# How can I make this output display in two columns rather than one long list?

Tags: php

Currently outputs as one long list

```
$output .= "<div class=\"selector\">\n";
$output .= "<form method=\"post\">\n";
if ($type == "new") {
    $output .= "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"type\" value=\"new\">\n";
    $output .= getPhaseDD("phase", $phase) . " &nbsp; ";
    $output .= "Day:" . getDayDD($day) . " &nbsp; ";
    $output .= "Number:" . getNumDD($num) . " ";
} else {
    $output .= "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"type\" value=\"existing\">\n";
    $output .= "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"phase\" value=\"{$phase}\">\n";
    $output .= "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"day\" value=\"{$day}\">\n";
    $output .= "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"num\" value=\"{$num}\">\n";
    $output .= "<div>Phase: {$phase}, Day: {$day}, Number: {$num}</div>";
}
if ($type == "new") {
    $output .= "<div><textarea name=\"msg\" rows=\"8\" cols=\"50\" id=\"msg\"   onkeyup=\"javascript:countTXT(this, 'cnt', 160);\" onkeydown=\"javascript:countTXT(this, 'cnt', 160);\">" . stripslashes($msg) . "</textarea></div>\n";
    $output .= "<div id=\"cnt\"></div>\n";
} else {
    $output .= "<div><textarea name=\"msg\" id=\"msg_{$day}_{$num}\" onkeyup=\"javascript:countTXT(this, 'cnt_{$day}_{$num}', 160);\" onkeydown=\"javascript:countTXT(this, 'cnt_{$day}_{$num}', 160);\">" . stripslashes($msg) . "</textarea></div>\n";
    $output .= "<div id=\"cnt_{$day}_{$num}\"></div>\n";
}
$output .= "<div>\n";
if ($type == "new") {
    $output .= "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"create_btn\" value=\"Create\" class=\"create_btn\">\n";
} else {
    $output .= "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"update_btn\" value=\"Update\" class=\"update_btn\"> \n";
    $output .= "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"delete_btn\" value=\"Delete\" class=\"delete_btn\" onclick=\"javascript:return confirmDelete();\">\n";
}
$output .= "</div>\n";
$output .= "</form>\n";
$output .= "</div>\n";
if ($type == "new") {
    $output .= "<script type=\"text/javascript\">countTXT(document.getElementById('msg'), 'cnt', 160);</script>\n";
} else {
    $output .= "<script type=\"text/javascript\">countTXT(document.getElementById('msg_{$day}_{$num}'), 'cnt_{$day}_{$num}', 160);</script>\n";
}
return $output;
```

I want to display in two columns, as there are quite a few messages being displayed, and it'll be cleaner than just one long scroll down.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Can you post what the output html currently looks like, and than what you want it to look like. Sometimes it is easier to write the php code if you know what your end result is supposed to be.

Comment: This is what it currently produces http://tinypic.com/r/1z14umr/6 and this is how I want it to show http://tinypic.com/r/29e1xl1/6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your posted code is created in a loop, x times. One way to do it is to wrap the 1st half in a `<div style="float:left">` and the 2nd have in either a `<div style="float:right">` or plain `<div>`.

eg.

```
// start the left float div
echo "<div style=\"float:left; padding:50px;\">";

// # of total divs in the 2 columns
$x = 12;

// for loop, change
for($i=1;$i<=$x;$i++){

// if we have reached the halfway mark, close the left float div and create the right side
if($i==(($x/2)+1)) {echo "</div><div style=\"padding:50px;\">";}

// this is where your div loop goes
echo "<div>Phase: Pre-Quit, Day: 1, Number:{$i}<br /><textarea cols=\"30\">Message {$i}</textarea></div>";}

// close the right div
echo "</div>";
```

you can see the example at - http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/9be-ax8

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do two divs, one float:left and the other float:right. If this is not dynamically generated (appears not to be), then you can just hard-code the HTML. Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm just confused on how to do that to make the list continue from the first column to the next

Comment: <div class="selector">
<form method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="type" value="existing">
<input type="hidden" name="phase" value="Pre-Quit">
<input type="hidden" name="day" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="num" value="3">
<div>Phase: Pre-Quit, Day: 1, Number: 3</div><div><textarea name="msg" id="msg_1_3" onkeyup="javascript:countTXT(this, 'cnt_1_3', 160);" onkeydown="javascript:countTXT(this, 'cnt_1_3', 160);">Message 1</textarea></div>
<div id="cnt_1_3"></div>
<div>
<input type="submit" name="update_btn" value="Update" class="update_btn">